# ios UIPickerView as popup

Tags: iphone, ios7, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView for each and every table row record. This is under the function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Here is the code part inside

```
picker = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280, -45, 30, 20)];
    [picker setDelegate:self];

    arrayColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayColors addObject:@"1"];
    [arrayColors addObject:@"2"];
    [arrayColors addObject:@"3"];
    [arrayColors addObject:@"4"];
    [arrayColors addObject:@"5"];
    [arrayColors addObject:@"6"];
    [arrayColors addObject:@"7"];
    [arrayColors addObject:@"8"];
    [arrayColors addObject:@"9"];
    [arrayColors addObject:@"10"];

    [cell addSubview:picker];
```

I wish to popup (as modal view) the picker, when I click on them. when I select the value it should close . Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You need to create a view controller class which contains `UIPickerView` and 2 `UIButton`, OK and Cancel. and present it modally. When user taps the OK button, you may send the event with the selected value on the `UIPickerView` to the table view controller via delegate and dismiss the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Override UITextField and implement the following methods.  Then insert your number picker into the cell, attach it to the value you are trying to modify (using UITextFieldDelegate or a change event) and you are done.

```
- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView {
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                          target:self
                                                                          action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)];
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    toolbar.items = @[spacer, item];
    return toolbar;
}

- (UIView *)inputView {
    if ((self.minimumNumber == 0) && (self.maximumNumber == 0)) {
        self.minimumNumber = 0;
        self.maximumNumber = 9;
    }
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    [pickerView selectRow:(self.number - self.minimumNumber) inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    return pickerView;
}

- (NSInteger)number {
    return [self.text integerValue];
}

- (void)setNumber:(NSInteger)number {
    self.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)number];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return self.maximumNumber - self.minimumNumber + 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)(row + self.minimumNumber)];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    self.number = (row + self.minimumNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here.

1. It doesn't make sense to have a separate picker instance for every row in your datasource. A much better design would have you associate the picker data with the row, and load that data in to a common picker when selected.

   For example, if you were making an App to take food orders, you would have each row represent a category (e.g. Drinks, Main meals, Side dishes, Desserts, etc), and link each category with an array of options for that category. An NSDictionary would be a good choice of internal data-store for this: your keys would be the categories (as constant NSStrings, perhaps) and the values would be NSArrays of the different options. Your table would be populated by an array of those constant NSString categories, so that when a cell is tapped you could look up which category it represents and use that to get the array of possible options.

   Then you would set those options on a single UIPickerView. Pickers are expensive - they eat up lots of memory and have lots of subviews. It's really bad practice to create a different picker for every set of options a picker might display.
2. Dismissing a UIPickerView when a user selects a value is a bad idea. The user may stop on one item on their way to select a different one (the one they really want). In that case, your App would be difficult to use and annoy them. Also, what would you do if they want to choose the first (default) option in the list?

It is possible to present UIPickerViews modally. The best way is probably to add the picker as an inputView to the cell. Unfortunately, UITableViewCell doesn't take an inputView itself. You can work around this by being clever with UIResponder and creating a subclass which allows you to assign an inputView and which allows itself to capture input focus:

```
@interface InputViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property ( nonatomic, strong, readwrite ) UIView * inputView;

@end

@implementation InputViewCell

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state

    if( selected && !self.isFirstResponder )
    {
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder  {  return YES; }

@end
```